# Center-/middle-align text with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How would I center-align (and middle-vertical-align) text when using PIL?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

> [Deprecation Warning](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deprecations.html#font-size-and-offset-methods): textsize is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use textbbox or textlength instead.

Code using `textbbox` instead of `textsize`.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


def create_image(size, bgColor, message, font, fontColor):
    W, H = size
    image = Image.new('RGB', size, bgColor)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    _, _, w, h = draw.textbbox((0, 0), message, font=font)
    draw.text(((W-w)/2, (H-h)/2), message, font=font, fill=fontColor)
    return image
```

```py
myFont = ImageFont.truetype('Roboto-Regular.ttf', 16)
myMessage = 'Hello World'
myImage = create_image((300, 200), 'yellow', myMessage, myFont, 'black')
myImage.save('hello_world.png', "PNG")
```

Result

[image: Result]

---

Use [`Draw.textsize` method](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw.textsize) to calculate text size and re-calculate position accordingly.

Here is an example:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

W, H = (300,200)
msg = "hello"

im = Image.new("RGBA",(W,H),"yellow")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
w, h = draw.textsize(msg)
draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), msg, fill="black")

im.save("hello.png", "PNG")
```

and the result:

[image: image with centered text]

If your fontsize is different, include the font like this:

```
myFont = ImageFont.truetype("my-font.ttf", 16)
draw.textsize(msg, font=myFont)
```

Comment: draw.textsize: (self, text, font=None)

Comment: If your font size is different, it's important to include your font like this:
`draw.textsize(msg, font=myFont)`, otherwise it won't get properly centered

Comment: How to ensure the text does not overflow out of Image?

Comment: How to center align multiline texts?

Comment: There is a mistake in the above code. It should be  (W-w/2,H-h/2) not ((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2). Tried the above way and found it.

Comment: Centered on an arbitrary point (x,y) it would be (x-w/2, y-h/2)

Answer (score 88):

Here is some example code which uses textwrap to split a long line into pieces, and then uses the `textsize` method to compute the positions.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import textwrap

astr = '''The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plains.'''
para = textwrap.wrap(astr, width=15)

MAX_W, MAX_H = 200, 200
im = Image.new('RGB', (MAX_W, MAX_H), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype(
    '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf', 18)

current_h, pad = 50, 10
for line in para:
    w, h = draw.textsize(line, font=font)
    draw.text(((MAX_W - w) / 2, current_h), line, font=font)
    current_h += h + pad

im.save('test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Textwrap is nice but keep in mind that the integer breakpoint you set for `width` is counting chars while PIL Images measure in pixels. I used a version of the above but added a while loop before the for loop that writes the lines. First I set an arbitrarily high char count to start, would then use textwrap to break the lines and would then use .textsize to measure the pixel width of the first output in the textwrap result list. If it fits, continue, else decrement my char count and measure again until the lines fit the image.

Comment: Great! thank you so much, this not just solved the alignment it solve the line height as well, I spent two days search for that problem solution and found it here. (the pad variable)

Answer (score 39):

One shall note that the `Draw.textsize` method is inaccurate. I was working with low pixels images, and after some testing, it turned out that `textsize` considers every character to be 6 pixel wide, whereas an `I` takes max. 2 pixels and a `W` takes min. 8 pixels (in my case). And so, depending on my text, it was or wasn't centered at all. Though, I guess "6" was an average, so if you're working with long texts and big images, it should still be ok.

But now, if you want some real accuracy, you better use the `getsize` method of the font object you're going to use:

```
arial = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 9)
w,h = arial.getsize(msg)
draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), msg, font=arial, fill="black")
```

As used in Edilio's link.

Comment: Not the answer to the OP's question, but nice urgently needed function. 1+

Comment: Important notice: This function `getsize` accepts non-latin chars like € or german Umlauts. `textsize` don't. ThumbsUp :-)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, even when above 2 answers were not creating the desired result. Thanks !

Comment: While `getsize` may accept non-latin characters, it's return value (especially height) is poorly defined in some cases (especially with non-ascii characters). For text alignment, you should use the [`getlength`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.getlength) function (from Pillow 8.0.0) for the width and font size for the height. An even better option is to use text anchors to let Pillow take care of centering for you.

Answer (score 35):

A simple solution if you're using [PIL 8.0.0](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html#imagedraw-text-anchor) or above: [text anchors](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/text-anchors.html)

```
width, height = # image width and height
draw = ImageDraw.draw(my_image)

draw.text((width/2, height/2), "my text", font=my_font, anchor="mm")
```

`mm` means to use the **middle** of the text as anchor, both horizontally and vertically.

See the anchors page for other kinds of anchoring. For example if you only want to center horizontally you may want to use `ma`.

Comment: This is a much better, more flexible and easy to use answer for the latest Pillow version

Comment: Nice one! This won't require libraqm too.

Answer (score 12):

The [PIL docs for ImageDraw.text](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text) are a good place to start, but don't answer your question.

Below is an example of how to center the text in an arbitrary bounding box, as opposed to the center of an image. The bounding box is defined as: `(x1, y1)` = upper left corner and `(x2, y2)` = lower right corner.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Create blank rectangle to write on
image = Image.new('RGB', (300, 300), (63, 63, 63, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

message = 'Stuck in\nthe middle\nwith you'

bounding_box = [20, 30, 110, 160]
x1, y1, x2, y2 = bounding_box  # For easy reading

font = ImageFont.truetype('Consolas.ttf', size=12)

# Calculate the width and height of the text to be drawn, given font size
w, h = draw.textsize(message, font=font)

# Calculate the mid points and offset by the upper left corner of the bounding box
x = (x2 - x1 - w)/2 + x1
y = (y2 - y1 - h)/2 + y1

# Write the text to the image, where (x,y) is the top left corner of the text
draw.text((x, y), message, align='center', font=font)

# Draw the bounding box to show that this works
draw.rectangle([x1, y1, x2, y2])

image.show()
image.save('text_center_multiline.png')
```

[The output shows the text centered vertically and horizontally in the bounding box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NykLO.png).

Whether you have a single or multiline message no longer matters, as PIL incorporated the `align='center'` parameter. However, it is for **multiline text only**. If the message is a single line, it needs to be manually centered. If the message is multiline, `align='center'` does the work for you on subsequent lines, but you still have to manually center the text block. Both of these cases are solved at once in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

Using a combination of `anchor="mm"` and `align="center"` works wonders. Example

```
draw.text(
        xy=(width / 2, height / 2),
        text="centered",
        fill="#000000",
        font=font,
        anchor="mm",
        align="center"
    )
```

Note: Tested where `font` is an `ImageFont` class object constructed as such:

`ImageFont.truetype('path/to/font.ttf', 32)`

Comment: I found the same solution and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `textsize` method (see [docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw.textsize)) to figure out the dimensions of your text object before actually drawing it.  Then draw it starting at the appropriate coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers did NOT take [text ascender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220683/5101148) into consideration.

Here's a backport of `ImageDraw.text(..., anchor="mm")`. Not sure if it's fully compatible with `anchor="mm"`, cause I haven't tested the other `kwargs` like `spacing`, `stroke_width` yet. But I ensure you this *offset* fix works for me.

```py
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import __version__ as pil_ver

PILLOW_VERSION = tuple([int(_) for _ in pil_ver.split(".")[:3]])


def draw_anchor_mm_text(
    im,
    xy,
    # args shared by ImageDraw.textsize() and .text()
    text,
    font=None,
    spacing=4,
    direction=None,
    features=None,
    language=None,
    stroke_width=0,
    # ImageDraw.text() exclusive args
    **kwargs,
):
    """
    Draw center middle-aligned text. Basically a backport of 
    ImageDraw.text(..., anchor="mm"). 

    :param PIL.Image.Image im:
    :param tuple xy: center of text
    :param unicode text:
    ...
    """
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    # Text anchor is firstly implemented in Pillow 8.0.0.
    if PILLOW_VERSION >= (8, 0, 0):
        kwargs.update(anchor="mm")
    else:
        kwargs.pop("anchor", None)  # let it defaults to "la"
        if font is None:
            font = draw.getfont()
        # anchor="mm" middle-middle coord xy -> "left-ascender" coord x'y'
        # offset_y = ascender - top, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220683/5101148
        # WARN: ImageDraw.textsize() return text size with offset considered.
        w, h = draw.textsize(
            text,
            font=font,
            spacing=spacing,
            direction=direction,
            features=features,
            language=language,
            stroke_width=stroke_width,
        )
        offset = font.getoffset(text)
        w, h = w - offset[0], h - offset[1]
        xy = (xy[0] - w / 2 - offset[0], xy[1] - h / 2 - offset[1])
    draw.text(
        xy,
        text,
        font=font,
        spacing=spacing,
        direction=direction,
        features=features,
        language=language,
        stroke_width=stroke_width,
        **kwargs,
    )
```

### Refs

- https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/text-anchors.html
- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4789
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220683/5101148
- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2486

Answer (score 2):

You may use following algorithm :

1. It is assumed that the main image has a white background.
2. Create an empty image (textImg) and draw the text on the top left corner of the image (or anywhere you wish).
3. Trim any whitespace from the textImg.
4. Finally, paste the textImg onto the main image using the dimensions of the rendered text, which are equal to the width and height of the textImg.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

text = "© Lorem Ipsum"

# this is main image we want to draw centered text
mainImg = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(600, 600), color='white')

# this is image text  that will hold trimmed text, create image with any size and draw text in it
textImg = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(200, 200), color='white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(textImg)
font = ImageFont.load_default() # ImageFont.truetype("your_font.ttf", 12)
draw.text((1, 1), text, fill='black', font=font)

# now trim white space from text image 
pixels = textImg.load()
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = textImg.width, textImg.height, 0, 0
for x in range(textImg.width):
    for y in range(textImg.height):
        if pixels[x, y] != (255, 255, 255):
            xmin, ymin = min(x, xmin), min(y, ymin)
            xmax, ymax = max(x, xmax), max(y, ymax)
textImg = textImg.crop((xmin, ymin, xmax+1, ymax+1))

# paste trimmed text image into main image and save
x, y = mainImg.width//2 - textImg.width//2, mainImg.height//2 - textImg.height//2
mainImg.paste(textImg, (x, y, x + textImg.width, y + textImg.height))
mainImg.save('mainImg.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the default font then you can use this simple calculation

```
draw.text((newimage.width/2-len(text)*3, 5), text,fill="black", align ="center",anchor="mm")
```

the main thing is
you have to divide the image width by 2 then get the length of the string you want and multiply it by 3 and subtract it from the division result

```
newimage.width/2-len(text)*3 #this is X position
```

**this answer is an estimation for the default font size used if you use a custom font then the multiplier must be changed accordingly. in the default case it is 3

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example to add a text in the center of the image

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter

msg = "hello"

img = Image.open('image.jpg')
W, H = img.size
box_image = img.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(4))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(box_image)
w, h = draw.textsize(msg)
draw.text(((W - w) / 2, (H - h) / 2), msg, fill="black")

box_image.show()
```