# How do I do text wrapping in pyCairo + Pango?

Tags: python, cairo, word-wrap, pango

What I need pyCairo to do is :

- generate an image of size 100x100 containing some text and an image from filesystem as background
- the text should be within a box which has text wrapping of size 20x20 with bottom left corner at (40,40).
- save this image

Comment: I switched to cairo-pango since I couldn't find a way for text-wrapping in PIL. If there are any other ways of doing Image manipulation and text wrapping (python only), please let me know..

Comment: Here is some example code for text-wrapping using PIL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970807/center-middle-align-text-with-pil/1970942#1970942.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find a way to get the Pango context and set [`pango.Layout.set_wrap()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-pangolayout.html#method-pangolayout--set-wrap) and `pango.Layout.set_width()`.