# Cannot align text with PIL textsize correctly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I use PIL to draw some text on the image.

I did as in this example [Center-/middle-align text with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970807/center-middle-align-text-with-pil) and it worked, however, when the text phrase changes the lines are not aligned.

Font is Verdana. Where could be the problem?

This displays correctly 5 pixels from the right side.

```
    colour = 'white'
    text = 'Attack Speed 3.7'
    font = ImageFont.truetype("static/fonts/verdana.ttf", 10)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)
    w, h = draw.textsize(text)
    draw.text((width - 5 - w, 110), text, colour,font=font)
```

This does not, about a half of the words are outside the image area:

```
    colour = 'white'
    text = 'One-hand hammer'
    font = ImageFont.truetype("static/fonts/verdana.ttf", 10)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)
    w, h = draw.textsize(text)
    draw.text((width - 5 - w, 95), text, colour,font=font)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calculating the width of text, you will only get an approximation if the font is not taken into account (especially if you use a variable-width font).

To fix this, calculate the text width like this:

```
w, h = draw.textsize(text, font)
```

Note that you may also need to adjust the size of the right-margin to take account of the new width calculation (five pixels is pretty small).

Comment: Thank you. 5 pixels is fine for me by the way.:)