# How to get the font pixel height using PIL's ImageFont class?

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL' ImageFont module to load fonts to generate text images.
I want the text to tightly bound to the edge, however, when using the ImageFont to get the font height, It seems that it includes the character's padding. As the red rectangle indicates.[image]

```
c = 'A'
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)
width = font.getsize(c)[0]
height = font.getsize(c)[1]
im = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.text((0, 0), 'A', (255, 255, 255), font=font)
im.show('charimg')
```

If I can get the actual height of the character, then I could skip the bounding rows in the bottom rectangle, could this info got from the font?
Thank you.

Comment: Now I wrote a small function to scan vertically the generated image text to find the padding for every font I use. As the font character image contains only front and back colors, it works well.

Comment: What is `c` in `font.getsize(c)[1]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, I have fixed the code block, please check it.

Comment: @HassanBaig c stands for the character in question i think

Comment: You can get size in one line: `width, height = font.getsize(c)`

Answer (score 63):

Exact size depends on many factors. I'll just show you how to calculate different metrics of font.

[image]

```
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', font_size)
ascent, descent = font.getmetrics()
(width, baseline), (offset_x, offset_y) = font.font.getsize(text)
```

- Height of red area: `offset_y`
- Height of green area: `ascent - offset_y`
- Height of blue area: `descent`
- Black rectangle: `font.getmask(text).getbbox()`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Correction: `(width, height), (offset_x, offset_y) = font.font.getsize(text)`. Also, `font.getmask(text)` will return an image having the size `(width, height)`, and a  `image_draw.text((0, 0), text, font)` basically draws that "mask" (returned by `getmask`) at an offset of `(offset_x, offset_y)`.

Comment: i guess your explanation only applies on English fonts as far as i test it is messy with other language fonts out there :/

Comment: This is outdated, and hopelessly broken with non-English text and non-standard fonts (e.g. significant italics). See my answer below using a new function in Pillow 8.0.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636273/1648883

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `font.font.getsize`, as this is a private API (although regrettably not prefixed by an underscore). OTOH `font.getsize` is broken for historical reasons and cannot be easily fixed.

Answer (score 24):

The top voted answer is outdated. There is a new function in Pillow 8.0.0: [`ImageDraw.textbbox`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textbbox).
See the [release notes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html#imagedraw-text-embedded-color) for other text-related functions added in Pillow 8.0.0.

**Note that `ImageDraw.textsize`, `ImageFont.getsize` and `ImageFont.getoffset` are broken**, and should not be used for new code. These have been effectively replaced by the new functions with a cleaner API. See the documentation for details.

To get a tight bounding box for a whole string you can use the following code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
image = Image.new("RGB", (200, 80))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 30)

draw.text((20, 20), "Hello World", font=font)
bbox = draw.textbbox((20, 20), "Hello World", font=font)
draw.rectangle(bbox, outline="red")
print(bbox)
# (20, 26, 175, 48)

image.show()
```

[image: bounding box example]

---

You can combine it with the new [`ImageDraw.textlength`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textlength) to get individual bounding boxes per letter:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
image = Image.new("RGB", (200, 80))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 30)

xy = (20, 20)
text = "Example"
draw.text(xy, text, font=font)

x, y = xy
for c in text:
  bbox = draw.textbbox((x, y), c, font=font)
  draw.rectangle(bbox, outline="red")
  x += draw.textlength(c, font=font)

image.show()
```

[image: letter bounding boxes example]

Note that this ignores the effect of kerning. Kerning is currently broken with basic text layout, but could introduce a slight inaccuracy with Raqm layout. To fix it you would add the text length of pairs of letters instead:

```py
for a, b in zip(text, text[1:] + " "):
  bbox = draw.textbbox((x, y), a, font=font)
  draw.rectangle(bbox, outline="red")
  x += draw.textlength(a + b, font=font) - draw.textlength(b, font=font)
```

Comment: FWIW: if you are looking for the fonts try `ArialFont = "/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Arial.ttf"` or if you want to know your fonts, try this for MACOS https://github.com/JayRizzo/JayRizzoTools/blob/master/pyGenRandFontObj.py

Comment: Can you (or someone) provide a link explaining why the alternatives `"are broken"`, in what ways, and what specifics are being violated?

Comment: Do you know how can I determine if extra space was used at the bottom due to descenders? I'm trying to find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78044997/determine-the-extra-space-added-by-descenders-using-pillow-text

Answer (score 3):

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

im = Image.new('RGB', (400, 300), (200, 200, 200))
text = 'AQj'
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=220)
ascent, descent = font.getmetrics()
(width, height), (offset_x, offset_y) = font.font.getsize(text)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle([(0, 0), (width, offset_y)], fill=(237, 127, 130))  # Red
draw.rectangle([(0, offset_y), (width, ascent)], fill=(202, 229, 134))  # Green
draw.rectangle([(0, ascent), (width, ascent + descent)], fill=(134, 190, 229))  # Blue
draw.rectangle(font.getmask(text).getbbox(), outline=(0, 0, 0))  # Black
draw.text((0, 0), text, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
im.save('result.jpg')

print(width, height)
print(offset_x, offset_y)
print('Red height', offset_y)
print('Green height', ascent - offset_y)
print('Blue height', descent)
print('Black', font.getmask(text).getbbox())
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNysa.jpg)

Calculate area pixel

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

im = Image.new('RGB', (400, 300), (200, 200, 200))
text = 'AQj'
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=220)
ascent, descent = font.getmetrics()
(width, height), (offset_x, offset_y) = font.font.getsize(text)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle([(0, offset_y), (font.getmask(text).getbbox()[2], ascent + descent)], fill=(202, 229, 134))
draw.text((0, 0), text, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
im.save('result.jpg')
print('Font pixel', (ascent + descent - offset_y) * (font.getmask(text).getbbox()[2]))
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIBlC.jpg)