# Determine the extra space added by descenders using Pillow text

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm adding text to images using python and pillow.

I draw a rectangle first, for the background, and then add an outline by drawing 4 lines.

The issue I have is that the text can seem as if it's not centered vertically.

As you can see in this image:

[image]

Since a descent is caused by the letters "q" and "y".

Compare that with boxes without descenders:

[image]

Technically the first one is correct in the sense that the box covers the whole box. But I want to have the ability to subtract the descent from the bottom, at least as an option in my program, so all single line boxes have the same height.

Getting the font:

```js
font = ImageFont.truetype(path, size=config.fontsize)
```

Getting some information:

```js
left, top, right, bottom = font.getbbox(line)
```

More code:

```js
    min_x = data["min_x"]
    min_y = data["min_y"]
    max_x = data["max_x"]
    max_y = data["max_y"]

    min_x_p = min_x - padding
    min_y_p = min_y - padding + top
    max_x_p = max_x + padding
    max_y_p = max_y + padding

    if config.bgcolor:
        bgcolor = get_color("bgcolor")
        alpha = utils.add_alpha(bgcolor, config.opacity)
        rect_pos = (min_x_p, min_y_p), (max_x_p, max_y_p)
        draw.rounded_rectangle(rect_pos, fill=alpha, radius=config.radius)

    if config.outline:
        ocolor = get_color("outline")
        owidth = config.outlinewidth
        halfwidth = owidth / 2

        draw.line([(min_x_p - halfwidth, min_y_p - halfwidth),
                   (max_x_p + halfwidth, min_y_p - halfwidth)], fill=ocolor, width=owidth)

        draw.line([(min_x_p - halfwidth, min_y_p - halfwidth),
                   (min_x_p - halfwidth, max_y_p + halfwidth)], fill=ocolor, width=owidth)

        draw.line([(min_x_p - halfwidth, max_y_p + halfwidth),
                   (max_x_p + halfwidth, max_y_p + halfwidth)], fill=ocolor, width=owidth)

        draw.line([(max_x_p + halfwidth, min_y_p - halfwidth),
                   (max_x_p + halfwidth, max_y_p + halfwidth)], fill=ocolor, width=owidth)

    draw.multiline_text((min_x, min_y), line, fill=fontcolor,
                        font=font, align=config.align)
```

So far I haven't been able to find a way to detect if a line of text is "descended".

I read about `font.getmetrics()` but that's general values, not specific to the text, but I think it can help.

Also the text/boxes can be multiline. I initially tried comparing height of the line with a dummy line with "aaaa" but that won't work on multiline.

This issue was resolved by me when I used cv2 to render the text, but for reasons I am now using pillow.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: This was answered here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/7830