# How Can I Centre Multiline Text Horizontally and Vertically Using PIL

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

As the title says, I want to centre multiline text onto a created image using PIL. I have used this code - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970942/7286028 but it only uses a middle-vertical align. I, however, want to have vertical and horizontal align. This should be easy but it complicated by padding pixels and other factors.

Thanks for any help,
Louis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the frame and the text are centred around the top left hand corner and each offset is in pixels.

the value W is the  width of the frame and H is the height of the frame.

the value w is the width of the text and h is the height of the text.

Top Left: `draw.text((0, 0), msg, fill="black")`

Top Right: `draw.text((W-w, 0), msg, fill="black")`

Bottom Left: `draw.text((0, H-h), msg, fill="black")`

Bottom Right: `draw.text((W-w, H-h), msg, fill="black")`

You can then use this idea to have the text a fraction of the distance along like halfway with both with this method ([seen in the linked discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970942/7286028)):

`draw.text(((W-w)/2, (H-h)/2), msg, fill="black")`

finally adding padding of a certain amount of pixels can be done by adding/subtracting an integer from the code:

`draw.text((((W-w)/2)-50, ((H-h)/2)-50), msg, fill="black")`

Github Link: https://github.com/Oliver-Tafe/StackOverflow/blob/master/PillowTextAlign.py

Comment: Yes it works for all formats of text as it is all relative to the text and window.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out!

Comment: I am still unsure on how to use it with multiline text. Surely draw.text(((W-w)/2, (H-h)/2), msg, fill="black") only works for single line text

Comment: It will work if you add line break (\n) characters in the string, where you want the new lines to be

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I will use textwrap.fill to add newlines in the string.