# Pillow, how to put the text in the center of the image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I use the Pillow (PIL) 6.0 and add text in the image. And I want to put the text in the center of the image. Here is my code,

```
import os
import string
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageOps

width, height = 100, 100

text = 'H'
font_size = 100

os.makedirs('./{}'.format(text), exist_ok=True)

img = Image.new("L", (width, height), color=0)   # "L": (8-bit pixels, black and white)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
w, h = draw.textsize(text, font=font)
draw.text(((width-w)/2, (height-h)/2), text=text, fill='white', font=font)

img.save('H.png')
```

## Here is the output:

[image]

## Question:

The text is in the center horizontally, but not in the center vertically. How can I put it in the center horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Have you compared `h` to the measured height of your "H"?  It can look like you're seeing a line-height issue...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center-/middle-align text with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970807/center-middle-align-text-with-pil)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Text always have some added space around characters, e.g. if we create a box that is the exact size reported for your 'H'

```
img = Image.new("L", (width, height), color=0)   # "L": (8-bit pixels, black and white)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
w, h = draw.textsize(text, font=font)
# draw.text(((width-w)/2, (height-h)/2), text=text, fill='white', font=font)
# img.save('H.png')
img2 = Image.new("L", (w, h), color=0)   # "L": (8-bit pixels, black and white)
draw2 = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
draw2.text((0, 0)), text=text, fill='white', font=font)
img2.save('H.png')
```

gives the bounding box:

[image]

Knowing that line height is normally ~20% larger than the glyphs/characters (+ some trial and error), and we can figure out the extent of the extra space. (The extra space for width is equally distributed so not interesting for centering).

```
draw2.text((0, 0 - int(h*0.21)), text=text, fill='white', font=font)
```

which moves the 'H' to the top:

[image]

Plugging this back into your original code:

```
img = Image.new("L", (width, height), color=0)   # "L": (8-bit pixels, black and white)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
w, h = draw.textsize(text, font=font)
h += int(h*0.21)
draw.text(((width-w)/2, (height-h)/2), text=text, fill='white', font=font)
img.save('H.png')
```

gives:

[image]

The `0.21` factor usually works well for a large range of font sizes for the *same* font. E.g. just plugging in font size 30:

[image]

Comment: will it handle non english letters as well ?

Comment: The process certainly does (remember the trial and error part), e.g. for an `Å` the `h += int(h*0.21)` needed to be `h += int(n*0.1)` because the ring make the letter taller than `H` (I'm a litte surprised that you haven't just tried this out yourself though, all the code is there...)

Answer (score 1):

Use of anchors can help with this

```py
import os
import string
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageOps

width, height = 100, 100

text = 'H'
font_size = 100

os.makedirs('./{}'.format(text), exist_ok=True)

img = Image.new("L", (width, height), color=0)   # "L": (8-bit pixels, black and white)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text(((width)/2, (height)/2), text=text, fill='white', font=font, anchor="mm", align='center')

img.save('H.png')
```

It works fine without `w` and `h` 
P.S.: I've tested it, and it can work well with non-English characters also