# How do I centralize text with the python PIL library?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

so guys, I did an event `ʻon_member_join`` with an image using a Pillow library, and I'm looking for help to make the PIL calculate the text size and center it according to the user's name, can I help?

````
    ```url = requests.get(member.avatar_url_as(format="png"))
    avatar = Image.open(BytesIO(url.content))
    avatar = avatar.resize((210, 210));
    bigsize = (avatar.size[0] * 2,  avatar.size[1] * 2)
    mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
    mask = mask.resize(avatar.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    avatar.putalpha(mask)

    saida = ImageOps.fit(avatar, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
    saida.putalpha(mask)

    fundo = Image.open('cogs/img/bem-vindo.png')
    fonte = ImageFont.truetype('cogs/img/college.ttf',42)
    
    escrever = ImageDraw.Draw(fundo)
    escrever.text(xy=(230,345), text=str(member),fill=(0,0,0),font=fonte)
    fundo.paste(saida, (357, 39), saida)

    fundo.save("cogs/img/welcome.png")```
````

but it’s only in a certain location, and I wanted to centralize it in the space
(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/738572311107469354/767727707710160896/unknown.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center-/middle-align text with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970807/center-middle-align-text-with-pil)

Comment: instead of 300/200 do I have to set my image resolution?