# Pillow center a text on an image only horizontally

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to center the texts only horizontally and to do the vertical part manually only I do not know how to center the horizontal part
the main image size is 1400x1400 pixels

```
background = Image.open("background.png")
    title_font = ImageFont.truetype("impact.ttf", 80)
    
    title_editeur_font = ImageFont.truetype("impact.ttf", 40)
    artiste1 = artiste.text
    titre1 = titre.text
    editeur1 = editeur.text
    image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(background)
    image_editable.text((300,300),titre1,(0,0,0),font = title_font)
    image_editable.text((300,400),artiste1,(0,0,0),font = title_font)
    image_editable.text((300,500),editeur1,(250,250,250),font = title_editeur_font)
        
    background.save("hello.png")
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66793499/724176