# Python pillow put text in center/middle

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-imageio

I am trying to put the text always in middle from very side. and i found this solution, but it doesnt work when i make the font size bigger.

I found this solution, it doesnt work too: [Center-/middle-align text with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970807/center-middle-align-text-with-pil)

This is my snippets:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw 
import textwrap


W, H = (2480,1754)
msg = "hello"
bg_color = "yellow"
font_name = 'Helvetica Neu Bold.ttf'
font_size = 500

im = Image.new("RGBA",(W,H), bg_color)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
myFont = ImageFont.truetype(font_name, font_size)

w, h = draw.textsize(msg)


# y_text=(H/2)-130

draw.text(((W-font_size)/2,(H-font_size)/2), msg, fill="black", font=myFont)

im.save("hello.png", "PNG")
```

The output is below:
[Click to see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPpqm.png)

Can anyone help me how can i put it in middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try option `anchor='mm'` to draw your text
[image]

```py
draw.text((W//2, H//2), msg, anchor='mm', fill="black", font=myFont)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, change:

```
w, h = draw.textsize(msg)

draw.text(((W-font_size)/2,(H-font_size)/2), msg, fill="black", font=myFont)
```

to:

```
w, h = draw.textsize(msg, font=myFont)

draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), msg, fill="black", font=myFont)
```

You are calculating the position from the font_size (500), but you need to be calculating from *how big the message will be when written in myFont, at that font_size*, and that is the (w, h) you get from asking draw.textsize() and giving it the font to work with.